# Process SQL result set entirely

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to work with a SQL result set in order to do some processing for each column (medians, standard deviations, several control statements included)

The SQL is dynamic so I don't know the number of columns, rows.

First I tried to use temporary tables, views, etc to store the results, however I did not manage to overcome the 30 character limit of Oracle columns when using the below sql:

```
create table (or view or global temporary table) as select * from (
SELECT
DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_V_COD_ANNOMESE, 
SUM(DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_N_NUM_EVENTI_CHZ +DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS. MAT_N_NUM_EVENTI) <-- exceeds the 30 character limit
FROM DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS
WHERE DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_V_COD_ANNOMESE >= '201301'
GROUP BY DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_V_COD_ANNOMESE
)
```

Second choice was to use some PL/SQL types to store the entire table information, so I could call it like in other programming languages (e.g. a matrix result[i][j]) but I could not find anything similar.

Third variant, using files for reading and writing: i did not try it yet; i'm still expecting a more elegant pl/sql solution

It's possible that I have the wrong approach here so any advice is more than welcome.

**UPDATE: Modifying the input SQL is not an option. The program has to accept any select statement.**

Comment: gotta love Oracle's 30 char limit.

Comment: In this case you have to use DBMS_SQL package, there you can parse any SQL statement dynamically and read each record and field. Check Oracle doce here: [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#BABEDAHF)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can alias both tables and fields. Using a table alias keeps references to it from producing walls of text in the query. Using one for a field gives it a new name in the output.

```
SELECT A.LONG_FIELD_NAME_HERE AS SHORTNAME
FROM REALLY_LONG_TABLE_NAME_HERE A
```

The auto naming adds _1 and _2 etc to differentiate the same column name coming from different table references. This often puts a field already borderline over the limit. Giving the fields names yourself bypasses this.

Comment: Hi Brian, remember I don't know the SQL behind so I can't put aliases

Answer (score 0):

You can put the alias also in dynamic SQL:

```
sqlstr := 'create table (or view or global temporary table) as select * from (
SELECT
   DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_V_COD_ANNOMESE, 
   SUM(DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_N_NUM_EVENTI_CHZ + DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_N_NUM_EVENTI) AS '||SUBSTR('SUM(DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_N_NUM_EVENTI_CHZ +DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_N_NUM_EVENTI)', 1, 30)
||' FROM DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS
WHERE DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_V_COD_ANNOMESE >= ''201301''
GROUP BY DMTTBF_MAT_MATURATO_BILL_POS.MAT_V_COD_ANNOMESE
)'
```